# Sending message to Clojure application from terminal

Tags: clojure

How does one send a message to a running clojure application? For example, if I have a particular variable or flag I want to set from the terminal when the uberjar is running - is this possible?

One way is to read a file in the application that you can change, but that sounds clunky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_socket_server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is by having your application host a nREPL (network REPL). You can then connect to your running app's nREPL and mess around.

For example, your app may look like this:

```
(ns sandbox.main
  (:require [clojure.tools.nrepl.server :as serv]))

(def value (atom "Hey!"))

(defn -main []
  (serv/start-server :port 7888)
  (while true
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (prn @value)))
```

While that's running you can `lein repl :connect localhost:7888` from elsewhere and change that `value` atom:

```
user=> (in-ns 'sandbox.main)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x12b094cf "sandbox.main"]
sandbox.main=> (reset! value "Bye!")
"Bye!"
```

By this time the console output of your app should look like this:

```
$ lein run
"Hey!"
"Hey!"
<...truncated...>
"Bye!"
"Bye!"
```

There are many options for interprocess communication on the JVM, but this approach is unique to Clojure.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a bunch.