# How to REPL uberjar inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I find the REPL a powerful and helpful tool. Currently, I run: `lein repl` to interact with my Clojure app via the REPL. However, I have just recently containerised my project. The app now sits inside a docker container as a single standalone uberjar file.

I would therefore like to know how to run the REPL on an uberjar file which is inside a docker container?

Comment: Refer to this question to embed REPL in your UberJar. After that, you can run it from within the container.

Answer (score 4):

As of Clojure 1.8 you can specify a [JVM option to host a REPL](https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_socket_server) without making any changes to your compiled application:

```
-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}"
```

In your `Dockerfile` your main command would now look something like this:

```
java -Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}" -jar path/to/app.jar
```

You can also add this option in a Leiningen `project.clj` rather than command line:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.server.repl={:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}"]
```

While your app is running you should be able to connect to that socket, assuming your container has the port exposed (`EXPOSE 5555` in `Dockerfile`):

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
user=> (+ 1 1)
2
user=> (doto 'sandbox.main require in-ns)
sandbox.main
sandbox.main=>
```

Alternatively, you can host a REPL from within your app's code as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209930).

```
(ns sandbox.main
  (:require [clojure.tools.nrepl.server :as serv]))

(defn -main []
  (serv/start-server :port 7888)
  ... do other stuff ...)
```

And connect to it with `lein repl :connect localhost:7888`.

Comment: I've exposed port 5555 in my docker file but I get ```Connection closed by foreign host.``` whilst running ```telnet 127.0.0.1 5555```. I've also update my docker-compose.yml to ```ports: - 3000:3000 - 5555:5555``` Does :jvm-opts need to be part of a profile?

Comment: @Freid001 are you setting that `clojure.server.repl` system property, either in your Dockerfile or in project.clj?

Comment: I am setting it in the project.clj

Comment: did you find a solution?